# In the Marvel universe, can a human have a baby with any non-human?

Tags: marvel

Can a human create a baby with a, preferably sentient, alien being through the "conventional" way?

Or more generally; can two species in the Marvel universe have sex and create a mix between species?

---

Note: a human-alien hybrid through experimentation does not count for the purpose of this question.

Comment: It would be better if you could also add tags: comics / MCU etc for clarity

Comment: @Shreedhar well, I basically wanted answers from all marvel universes, so i thought the marvel tag would be enough

Comment: For Star Lord and Gamora's sake, I sure hope so.

Comment: In your title question, you say “any” which is rather sweeping.  Then “preferably” which makes an earthworm eligible though not preferred.

Comment: It's a fairly common superhero comic book universe genre convention that almost any humanoid creature or sentient entity that can assume a humanoid form,  can produce viable offspring with humans, or other humanoid creatures..

Comment: In English, "any" is ambiguous, as it can stand for ∃ (as in "Is there any fruit here?") or ∀ (as in "Any fruit that is left here will be thrown out."). Could you reword your question to make it more clear which you mean?

Comment: I would assume the answer, for the specific phrasing of *any* non-human, is technically "no". For example, I doubt flerkens can reproduce successfully with humans under natural conditions.

Comment: "*can two species in the Marvel universe have sex and create a mix between species?*"  They can if they writers want them to.

Comment: @DavidH: the question does not ask that the offsprings should be able to reproduce, so it opens the door to hybrids between (close) species. Anyway, many SF and fantasy works seem to ignore that basic rule of biology.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Yes...

...and it is literally the main plot point of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*. Ego, a Celestial, has created off spring with various other species across the galaxy. Star-Lord, aka Peter Quill, is one of those hybrid children.

> **Ego:** Not long after. It was with Meredith that I first experienced love. I called her my river lily. And from that love, Peter... you.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

We later find out he's also done it with various other species, he initially shows us this diorama.

> **Ego:** Out of all my labors the most beguiling was attempting to graft my DNA with that of another species. I hoped the result of such a coupling would be enough to power the expansion.
>
> **Ego (O.S.):** I had Yondu deliver some of them to me. It broke the Ravager code - but I compensated him generously. And, to ease his conscience, I told him I would never hurt them.
>
> **Ego:** That was true. They never felt a thing. But, one after the other, they failed me. None of them had the Celestial genes. Until you, Peter. Out of all my spawn, only you have carried the connection to the light.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

[image: Diorama showing Ego's pairings with different species.]
<sub><sub>*FWIW I believe the circle in this image is down to a fan theory that Mantis is Peter's sister i.e. Ego's daughter but it's the best quality image I could find so you can safely ignore it.*</sub></sub>

We later see a lot of his children, in a cave of skulls and skeletons.

> **Gamora:** The bodies in the caverns, who are they?!
>
> [...]
>
> **Mantis:** The bodies are his children.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

[image: Ego's cave of his children's skeletons]

Comment: so, only celestials can have children with other species?

Comment: @Termatinator I'm not 100% sure but in the MCU at least I believe it is the only case.

Comment: There was also talk at the beginning of the movie from Ayesha: "_Well... perhaps someday you could give me a history lesson in the archaic ways of our ancestors... for academic purposes._" Implying that it might be possible to procreate in that way...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: That doesn't imply it works cross-species though. Ayesha's ancestors procreated like humans still do. Her request isn't (necessarily) focused on creating a human-Sovereign hybrid.

Comment: @Flater Maybe, but she was talking about how their species procreates in the line immediately preceding that one, so it's still relevant.  Also, though we don't know it yet, Quill is half-Celestial, and we know per above that his dad procreated with all kinds of aliens, presumably including at least one Sovereign.  So the implied hybrid of 1/2 Sovereign, 1/4 Celestial, 1/4 Human is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 27):

## The answer is: Yes!

TL;DR, but here are a few I could remember:

1. **Star Lord** (*MCU*): Reiterating *TheLethalCarrot's* answer, Star Lord is a Celestial-Human hybrid as mentioned in Guardians of the Galaxy vol.2.
2. **Star Lord** (*Marvel comics*): The comic book version of Peter Quill is the son of Meredith Quill and J'Son of Spartax (so, a human-Spartoi hybrid).
3. **Skaar** : He is the son of The Hulk and the Shadow Queen Caiera the Oldstrong (a Sakaaran)
4. **Hiro-Kala** : He is the second son of The Hulk and Caiera
5. **Daydream** : She is the daughter of Betty Ross (Red She-Hulk) and the dream-creeping demon lord Nightmare (he's a demon, so I'd say, he falls under the non-human category).

Comment: I believe Scarlet Witch and Vision also had a child in the comics, although I believe Wanda had to use her powers in order to make that possible.

Comment: Would Nightcrawler also count? From what I can find, his father is the demon Azazel, and his mother is the (mutant) human Mystique.

Comment: @AdmiralJota Depending on the continuity, sometimes Azazel's species are actually humans with the same Mutant power, who bred into a sub-species called the Neyaphem.  (And who are long-time enemies with another Mutant sub-species called the Cheyarafim, who all had the same power as Warren Worthington III) - so in that case Nightcrawler would be more "mixed-race" than "mixed-species"

Comment: @aleppke yeah you’re right. they were named Tommy and William . But the OP asked for children conceived thorough sex. So I didn’t include them in the answer.

Comment: @AdmiralJota but Azazel is a mutant right (at least I thought so)? Neyapham, as his species was called is mentioned as “ancient mutants”. So I don’t think Nightcrawler might count in this case.

Comment: I can't remember their origins well enough to say if they fit in the copulation category, but Pitt and Adam-X are two more fairly obscure Marvel characters that were half human and half alien.

Answer (score 20):

> Or more generally; can two species in the Marvel universe have sex and
>   create a mix between species?

Yes - A simple, "normal person" example would be Rhomann Dey's family:

[image: Rhomann Dey's Family]

Rhomann Dey is Xandarian and his wife is Krylorian ([MCU Wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Rhomann_Dey%27s_Daughter))

Comment: Good catch, except none of them are human as the original question was asking...

Comment: @DarrellHoffman I was addressing "Or more generally; can two species in the Marvel universe have sex and create a mix between species?"

Comment: Fair enough.  I also wasn't sure if she was confirmed as his actual daughter or his wife's from a previous partner, given that we know almost nothing about them from their brief film appearances.  (Do either the wife or daughter even have lines?)  I'm assuming there's more in the comics though...

Comment: Before I read this answer, I thought Rhomann Dey was a human. Oh well. @DarrelHoffman The guy is white, his wife is red and their daughter is pink. How much more explicit did you want it to be?